# .htaccess skips mod_rewrite and directs to ErrorDocument 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` which works wonderfully on a few websites of mine.  However, I have uploaded it to another website (on the same host, different domain) and it is now defaulting to the error 404 page; which is displaying correctly.

Example URL: `https://www.example.ca/resources-and-links/documents/`

The `.htaccess` first checks to see if there is a actual `.php` file with first sub-directory, in the example `resources-and-links.php`.  If it does exists it will serve up that page and break down the rest of the sub-directories into  the query strings provided.

If the `resources-and-link.php` doesn't exsits, it directs it to the `content.php` to check it against pages in the database and serve it if the url matches one of that in the database.  If it doesn't the `content.php` page shows a custom error 404 page.

This works on a sub-domain of said website `https://sub.example.com` which runs the cms system I built but not the root domain and as said before; shows the `ErrorDocument` instead.  As well, I've used this same `.htaccess` on many of my other websites without a problem.

I used PHP to show that `mod_rewrite` is available so are there any reasons why it would not work on the root domain?  Why is it skipping straight to the `ErrorDocument` and serving `/404.php`?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*)) /$1.php?ax=$3&do=$5&third=$7&fourth=$9 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/(.*)$ /content.php?url=$1/$2 [L]
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hello Dawson, how about mentioning `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` inside your `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block once? Kindly try it once and let me know then, how it goes.

Comment: I have placed it inside the block.  Still the same effect as before.